# Xcode: will only fail on 4 inch 64-bit device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, button

I'm building an iOS app in Xcode. I've run into an issue with my build. Specifically, when I run my app on my physical device (iPhone 5) and any simulated 32-bit device, it runs fine. But if I use the 4 inch 64bit device, I get the following error on a specific line of code:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

I'm guessing this error means nothing as I don't get it with any other device.

I have tried cleaning my build and build folder, and even reverting to earlier commits that didn't have this issue. That didn't work (much to my surprise).

When I first had this error, I had something along the lines of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672603/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib) relating to images ("Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier ..."). Specifically, I think my issue is a due to a copy-and-paste of a UIButton in Interface Builder. I have since deleted this button.

How do I resolve this issue?

When I run the program on the only simulated device that causes this problem, I get the following output on the console:

```
2014-03-16 16:35:54.922 iSparse[3743:60b] 
(lldb)
(lldb) p idx[0]
(int) $0 = 35353
(lldb) p idx[1]
(int) $1 = 17508
(lldb) p colorPlane[0]
(float) $2 = 218
(lldb) p y_r[0]
(float) $3 = 0
(lldb) p y_r[1]
(float) $4 = 0
```

This tells me that `idx` and `colorPlane` appear to be valid arrays and since `y_r` is not filled with pixel values, that line of code not executed.

The function where this error occurs is

```
-(void)makeMeasurements2:(UIImage *)image atRate:(float)rate
                     red:(float *)y_r green:(float *)y_b blue:(float *)y_g
                ofLength:(int)length idx:(int *)idx{
    // vDSP_vgathr is equivalent to a[i] = b[c[i]] (!)
    int pix = image.size.height * image.size.width;
    float * array = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * pix * 4);
    float * colorPlane = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * pix);
    // get data

    [self.dwt imageToRawArray:image into:array pix:length];
    int n;

    // perform wavelet, 2D on image
    // using color planes, all of that
    // vDSP_vgathr is the equivalent of a[i] = b[c[i]]
    for (n=0; n<3; n++) {
        // copy from "array", which is RGBA,RGBA,RGBA...
        // and get the colorplane out
        cblas_scopy(pix, array+n, 4, colorPlane, 1);

        // the do-what-you-want code should go here.
        if (n == 0) {
            vDSP_vgathr(colorPlane, (const vDSP_Length *)idx, 1, y_r, 1, (int)(rate*pix));
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            vDSP_vgathr(colorPlane, (const vDSP_Length *)idx, 1, y_b, 1, (int)(rate*pix));
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            vDSP_vgathr(colorPlane, (const vDSP_Length *)idx, 1, y_g, 1, (int)(rate*pix));
        }
        cblas_scopy(pix, colorPlane, 1, array+n, 4);
    }

    catlas_sset(pix, 255, array+3, 4);

    image = [self.dwt UIImageFromRawArray:array image:image forwardInverseOrNull:@"null"];
    free(array);
    free(colorPlane);
```

It fails on the first `vDSP_vgathr` in the for-loop.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and post both the symbolicated log and the code where the exception occurs. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually caused by accessing a deallocated object so running with `NSZombies` may also help track down the error.

Comment: Please show the actual code.

Comment: Added debugger output and the function where it fails.

Comment: Odd, EXC_I386_GPFLT doesn't sound like an Arm64 error. Or is that in the 64bit simulator?

Comment: Try to change all your int types to NSInterger

Comment: That's in the 64bit simulator, not on an actual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted *does* have to do with the error, and it's not Xcode specific. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22586119/1141256) (which uses the same function call!) for more detail.