# Xcode 6 Beta 6 CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor: 2.000000

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting the following errors:

```
CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor: 2.000000
Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.example.project"
```

I' m getting the errors since I set a "Selected Image" for a Tab Bar Item in Interface Builder:

[image]

I've added the file into Xcode:

[image]

The setting is written into the storyboard file:

```
<tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="..." image="config.png" selectedImage="config_filled.png" id="5Wh-7m-Y4H"/>
```

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 6

I know about [Error: CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor : 2.000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011106/error-cuicatalog-invalid-asset-name-supplied-null-or-invalid-scale-factor) but that doesn't help me.

What could cause that the asset name is null? I've reentered the image name, I also tried with cleaning and rebuilding but the error stays (and no image appears)

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error, and no mention of an invalid scale factor. I am using asset catalogs with all image sizes supplied. This appears to be a definite bug. My final solution was to simply exclude the selected image, as I don't see that it is worth pursuing further.

Comment: Duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672603/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib

Answer is there.

Comment: @GabrielCartier Please read my question carefully, I already checked that when I asked my question.

Answer (score 29):

In Xcode 6.1, some attributes in Attributes Inspector did not work, but you can use "User Defined Runtime Attributes" to solve this problem.

I solve it like this:
[image]

Comment: I've tried this solution and, in my particular case, it works. Thanks, @mistyhua.

Comment: Works perfectly. I had my images in a .xcassets file.

Comment: Just noticed, that the error message still appears, but the images are now visible. I ended up doing it programmatically.

Comment: Don't set "Selected Image" in "Attributes Inspector". @Danniel

Answer (score 18):

I've finally ended up using this nasty code in AppDelegate:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
((UITabBarItem *)tabBarController.tabBar.items[0]).selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"light_filled"];
((UITabBarItem *)tabBarController.tabBar.items[1]).selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"umbrella_filled"];
((UITabBarItem *)tabBarController.tabBar.items[2]).selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"config_filled"];
```

Hopefully Apple will fix this bug soon.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic Yeah, I know. Strange that Apple doesn't notice/fix this bug.

Comment: The whole thing is barely working. Just when I implemented your workaround, code completion for Swift stopped working. No comment.

Comment: Yes only solution I found was to set the images programatically and remove the selectedImage and the Image properties in my storyboard for each tabbaritem

Answer (score 5):

Leave the "Selected Image" for a Tab Bar Item in Interface Builder **empty** should remove the warning message.

Comment: But then I still don't have a selected image?

Comment: Somehow the selected image here does not apply to my app. The only way to make it work is to use "User Defined Runtime Attributes"  just as above.

Comment: so please post a comment above. This answer is on its own pretty useless.

Comment: Not enough reputations to do that I am afraid. :(

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to check all your `UIImageViews` in story, sometimes if you delete `UIImageview` and restore them with Cmd+z, the image in the `UIImageView` becomes `"Unknown"`. I think it is a bug, since you can still see the image in the storyboard.

Solution: Select the image again in the `UIImageView` in storyboard

Comment: thanks! When I checked UIImageView, it is showing with **Unknown** now I removed and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set the entry of the tabBar image in Images.xcassets to *Render As: Template Image*

This solved the errors and warnings.

Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25879805/4769084) from another question.

Comment: That sounds logical. I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

My swift workaround because of lack of code completion was this

```
    let secondItem = tabBarController.tabBar.items![1] as UITabBarItem
    secondItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home-selected")
```

This was put in the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Answer (score -2):

Try leaving off the ".png" extension, that would have fixed certain IB image loading issues in the past.