# Using IB's "User Defined Runtime Attributes" on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tintcolor

I have a static `UITableView` with a single section; that section has two `UITableViewCell`s each having its own `UIImageView` (see screenshot). I would like to modify the image used in the cell so that it uses a rendering mode of `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` (so that the image will honor tintColor).

I've selected the `UITableViewCell` and set the following in IB's "User Defined Runtime Attributes" (see screenshot):
Note:  2 is the value of `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`.

When I run the app Xcode generates the following warning:

```
Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIImageView): [<UIImageView 0x7fa490550d30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Also, I would like to not have to drop down to code for this - I want to stick with they Storyboard if possible.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting this as a String type instead of Number?

Comment: I've tried setting things like this:
imageView.image.renderingMode String "2" or imageView.image.renderingMode String 2 or imageView.image.renderingMode String UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate

Comment: It looks like renderingMode is read-only.  That means this wouldn't work to modify it.

Comment: If you think this is the answer let me know and I'll post it in the answer for you to check. Otherwise I'll keep searching.

Comment: @BrooksHanes As you said, since renderingMode is read-only I had to go another route. I'll post more when I can. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since `imageView.image.renderingMode` is a read-only property you have to do something else if you don't want to drop down to writing code.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create a new entry in Images.xcassets. Images in xcassets allow you to select *Render As: Template Image*.

[image]